# Change Angular2 Material Component ( e.g. Select controller ) outside from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

If it is possible...

I have a site: www.recognitiongame.com
I have started to use Angular2 Material Components ( Autocomplete, Button... ).

I want to change the "Main theme:" DropDownlist to Angular2 Material Select Component.

I have this:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Main theme:" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let maintheme of mainthemes" [value]="maintheme.id">
  {{ maintheme.value }}
</mat-option>
```

How can I access the Angular2 Component "selectedValue" variable from outside?
Something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
 **Change the selectedValue?**
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not likely to be possible. Polymer (custom web components generally) would be better if you REALLY require something like this. But the questions really is, why do you even want to do this.

Comment: In my Website: 
On the left side there is a "Proposal" panel, where you can choose from topics. 
Now: If somebody click the suggested topic on the left, the topic path's displayed in the middle. 
I want to change the DropDownList to Angular2 Material Select Component and that's why I want to know how to change the "Main theme:" mat-select Component.

Answer (score 0):

```
public _selectedValue = window['selectedValue']
public set selectedValue(_selectedValue){
   this._selectedValue = _selectedValue;
   window['selectedValue'] = _selectedValue;
}

public get selectedValue(){
   return this._selectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Please, highlight your improvements.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. If I change the window['selectedValue'] outside of Angular, the _selectedValue will change?